My pagination won't display in Laravel 11 Livewire 3
I want to create a simple system using Laravel 11, Livewire 3 and Tailwind CSS but I have a problem when I want to display pagination on my data, I can't display pagination on my system.
Dashboard
<x-main>
   <x-slot name="title">Dashboard</x-slot>

   <div class="container mx-auto">
      Dashboard

      @dump($dataUsers)

      @foreach ($dataUsers as $item)
         <div class="">
            test
         </div>
      @endforeach

      Paginate {{ $dataUsers->links() }}
   </div>
</x-main>

x-main
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    @vite('resources/css/app.css')
    <title>{{ $title ?? 'Page Title' }}</title>
    <livewire:styles />
</head>

@auth
<livewire:component.navbar>
    @endauth

    <body>
        {{ $slot }}
        <livewire:scripts />
    </body>

</html>

route
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', function () {
        return view('layouts.pages.admin.dashboard', ['dataUsers' => User::paginate(1)]);
    })->name('dashboard');
});

like this

I have tried to find references on the internet but I did not find it, in this case I did not change any config in livewire 3. I have tried to create a new laravel 11 project and I still encounter the same problem.

I've never seen <livewire:styles /> and <livewire:scripts />, I suggest you to replace them with @livewireStyles and @livewireScripts. You may also need to add @vite('resources/js/app.js'). In the  Dashboard class you must also use the WithPagination trait.

<livewire:component.navbar> should be inside the body.
